# React not re-rendering component when setState is called from the method which is called on a button click

Tags: reactjs, use-state

I am trying to make the values in object empty once Login button is clicked after alerting the message. But that is not changing the value of useState object and hence not re-rendering the component. Can anyone please help me with this?

```
import React from 'react'
import { useState } from 'react';

function Login() {
  const [user, setUser] = useState({
    prn: "",
    password: ""
  });
  
  const doLogin = () => {
    alert("Welcome " + user.prn + " " + user.password);
    setUser(
      {
        prn: "",
        password: ""
      }
    )
    console.log(user);
  }

  const onInputChange = (event) => {
    // code to change state
  }

  return (
    <div className='login'>
      <input 
        type="number" name="prn"
        defaultValue={user.prn}
        onChange={onInputChange}
      />
      <br /> <br />
      <input 
        type="password" name="password"
        defaultValue={user.password} 
        onChange={onInputChange}
      />
      <br /> <br />
      <input type="button" value="Login" onClick={doLogin} />
    </div>
  );
}

export default Login
```

Comment: You're not storing any newly entered user credentials in the state as seen in the `doLogin()` function which sets the state to the same values as the initial state. You need to extract the new values from the inputs and set it to the state when login button is clicked. `doLogin()` function should have some form of validation logic and then only submit the login request

Comment: You can't use defaultValue with useState hook, you have to use useRef hook and the code structure will have to change as you will not be able to pass an object in useRef.  defaultValue is used for uncontrolled state input field.

Answer (score 1):

Your inputs are not controlled, so your state value updates are not reflected. To fix this, add `value` prop to your input like so:

```
      <input
        type="number"
        name="prn"
        value={user.prn}
        onChange={onInputChange}
      />
      <br /> <br />
      <input
        type="password"
        name="password"
        value={user.password}
        onChange={onInputChange}
      />
```

Edit 1: I added the onChange handler in the sandbox, and adding it here as well

```
  const onInputChange = (event) => {
    // code to change state
    setUser((prev) => ({
      ...prev,
      [event.target.name]: event.target.value
    }));
  };
```

[Here's a sandbox as well](https://codesandbox.io/s/hopeful-hofstadter-sbzqpe?file=/src/Login.js)

Comment: I did that but if I add value then I am not able to enter any text in input field.

Comment: That's because in your code you're not handling the onChange event, see my sandbox.

Answer (score 0):

**First**, let's address the issue of the state value seemingly not updating.

Setting the state in React acts like an async function.
Meaning that the when you set the state and put a `console.log` right after it, it will likely run before the state has actually finished updating.

Which is why we have `useEffect`, a built-in React hook that activates a callback when one of it's dependencies have changed.

**Example:**

```js
useEffect(() => {
   console.log(user)
   // Whatever else we want to do after the state has been updated.
}, [user])
```

This `console.log` will run only after the state has finished changing and a render has occurred.

- Note: "user" in the example is interchangeable with whatever other state piece you're dealing with.

Check the [documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html) for more info about this.

---

**Second**, as for the reason the values of the inputs in the UI are not updating when you set the state, is likely due to using the `defaultValue` attribute on the inputs.
Try using the regular `value` attribute instead.